# Save a file on Android documents?

Tags: android, excel

I'm creating an excel file directly on Android. The code is working fine, I can verify the .xls has been created and I can check it's content from a rooted phone.
However I want save the excel file in a different folder from the project itself (which is /data/data/mypackage/files/). I want to save it on the normal phone documents, which would be something like "/storage/sdcard0/Documents/test.xls". I get a message saying "Permission denied" when trying to save the .xls file on that folder.

How can I get access to those folders?

Here I'm creating the excel file

```
WriteExcel test = new WriteExcel();
            test.setOutputFile("/data/data/com.example.interfaz/files/test.xls"); // here is where I want to save the file to "/storage/sdcard0/Documents/test.xls"
            try {
                test.write();

            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page for more info on saving files:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission

Make sure you have the permission in your manifest to write files to external storage:

```
<manifest ...>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm so stupid. I thought I already added the permission but it was READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE instead of WRITE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add permissions to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You should also not hard code the SDCard location since it can, and does, changes between devices.

Instead, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: Forgot that in my answer, but amen  that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`is definitely the way to go.